# How to flex wrap 4 elements 2 by 2

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to keep my logo "Reservia" and my LI "S'inscrire" on the same line and wrap my 2 other LI "Hebergement" and "Activités" on a line under this first one but it doesn't work.

Here is my Header

```
<header>
    <div id="containerHeader">
        <img src="images/logo/Reservia.svg" class="test" alt="Logo reservia">
        <nav class="Navmenu">
            <ul class="liMenu">
                <li class="liMenu--list liMenu--list_nocolor">
                  <a href="#containerHebergement" class="link--navbar">Hebergement</a>
                </li>
                <li class="liMenu--list liMenu--list_nocolor">
                  <a href="#containerActivites" class="link--navbar">Activités</a>
                </li>
                <li class="liMenu--list liMenu--list_blue">
                  <a href="#" class="link--navbar test">S'inscrire</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

And here is my CSS

```
#containerHeader{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.navMenu,
.liMenu {
    justify-content: center;
    padding-right: 80px;
}
.liMenu--list {
    list-style: none;
}
.test{
    order: -1;
}
.link--navbar {
    border-bottom: 4px solid lightgrey;
    border-top: none;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.link--navbar:hover {
    border-top: none;
}
```

And I put my 2 screenshots ( what it looks like and what I want ) :)

Thanks a lot

[image: what it looks like]

[image: what I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
img, li {
  width: 50%
}
```

Try adding 50% width to the img and li elements. This will ensure that a single element takes up half the width, which will result in two elements per row.

You may need to use media queries if you want a different look for different devices.